# Going on eurotunnel without a visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I am travelling with my wife who holds a Bangladeshi passport with full rights to reside in the UK. Can she travel and get a visa at the border?

Comment: *with full rights to reside in the uk* What do you mean by this? What specifically is her immigration status?

Comment: Where are you travelling from and to?

Comment: I'm guessing that, since you've tagged this 'schengen', that you're travelling *from* the UK, *to* France through the tunnel?

Comment: There's no such thing as visas on arrival in the UK or Schengen. Either you don't need a visa because you are from a country the citizens of which don't need one (EU and visa waiver countries, i.e. countries listed on Annex II in the case of Schengen), or you need a visa, and you will need to get that in advance.

Comment: Can you also clarify what your own status us (i.e. citizenship and/or residence)? If you are an EU citizen, does she have an article 10 residence card? Are you travelling together?

Comment: In addition to the comments and answers that visas are not offered on the border, please be aware that passport control for the destination country takes place in the country of origin. French border police check passports and visas in London before you board the Eurostar, or in Cheriton before you board the Euroshuttle and vice versa for the UK in France.

Comment: I was under the impression that the schegen area did do visas on arrival in some circumstances. Most notablly for this question family members of EU citizens. Has that changed?

Answer (score 2):

Neither the UK nor the Schengen area (which includes France) issues visas on arrival. Whichever way you're travelling, if your wife needs a visa, she needs to get it before you set off.

Comment: The Article 35 of the Schengen Visa Code deals with the exceptions on issuing a visa upon entry. Proving that it was not possible to get a visa in a normal manor to their satisfaction is one of them.

Comment: @MarkJohnson OK, but that's surely designed to cover things like long-haul flights making emergency landings in Schengen. It's hard to imagine a situation in which this would apply to a Eurostar trip.

Comment: Yes, these are exceptions. Passport lost while outside, entering without proof with new passport etc. For the UK also a possibility that an Immigration Officer would take into consideration when considering granting leave to enter.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a visa for the UK (you can easily check on https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) you must [apply](https://www.gov.uk/apply-to-come-to-the-uk) and your application must be approved **before** you travel to and arrive in the UK.
AFAIK Visa are NOT issued on arrival.

Comment: Would the downvoters care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: I agree, no visa on arrival in the UK.

Comment: It looks to me like the OP is asking about travel to France, not the UK.

Comment: It looks to me that the Eurotunnel is somehow involved, I wouldn't dare guessing which direction OP is going.